# Why won't enter the "if"?

Tags: java, tree

I'm trying to look for a integer in a tree, here is the code of the method:
The method is supposed to search all the nods in the tree and when find the integer return true.

```
   private boolean mostrarCentral(No2 no, double x) {
      boolean resp =false;

      if (no != null) {

        mostrarCentral(no.esq,x); // Elementos da esquerda

        System.out.println(" No is " + no.elemento.getProbMandante() + " |x is " + x);

       if(no.elemento.getProbMandante() == x){
                resp = true;
         }

        mostrarCentral(no.dir,x); // Elementos da direita.

      }
      return resp;
   }
```

The problem is that for some reason won't enter the "if" that testing if the integer is there, the print shows this:

```
 No is 60.0 |x is 15.1
 No is 45.4 |x is 15.1
 No is 60.7 |x is 15.1
 No is 30.5 |x is 15.1
 No is 75.9 |x is 15.1
 No is 60.2 |x is 15.1
 No is 45.9 |x is 15.1
 No is 45.7 |x is 15.1
 No is 60.1 |x is 15.1
 No is 60.0 |x is 15.1
 No is 15.1 |x is 15.1
 No is 30.0 |x is 15.1
 No is 30.0 |x is 15.1
 No is 30.4 |x is 15.1
 No is 45.1 |x is 15.1
 No is 60.3 |x is 15.1
 No is 60.8 |x is 15.1
 Don't exist
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `No2` class? Also `getProbMandante()`

Comment: Where do you see the point in ignoring the returned values of your recursive calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that it probably is entering into the if, you just aren't returning the result. I imagine something like this will work.

```
   private boolean mostrarCentral(No2 no, double x) {
      boolean resp =false;

      if (no != null) {

        resp = resp || mostrarCentral(no.esq,x); // Elementos da esquerda

        System.out.println(" No is " + no.elemento.getProbMandante() + " |x is " + x);

       if(no.elemento.getProbMandante() == x){
                return true;
         }

        resp = resp || mostrarCentral(no.dir,x); // Elementos da direita.

      }
      return resp;
   }
```

And if you want to shorten that to remove the print statement.

```
   private boolean mostrarCentral(No2 no, double x) {
      if (no != null) {
        return no.elemento.getProbMandante() == x || 
                    mostrarCentral(no.esq,x) || 
                    mostrarCentral(no.dir,x);
      }
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, it isn't the most efficient way, though, since it still has to search the whole tree. You just needed to save the result of the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement *is*  entered **but** you never do anything with `resp` which you set to true in that statement. I guess what you wish to do is return `true` as soon as you find `no.elemento.getProbMandante() == x`, so instead of setting `resp = true` just `return true` instead. You do not need `resp` at all if you're only searching the tree for *one* particular node.

If you do not find such a node (which is the case where you currently do `return resp`), you can return `false` instead.
(The reason why `resp` is not `true` when your method returns *even if you find a node* is that it's a recursive method with `resp` as a local variable.)